# TextArea not saving to mySQL if over 512 Bytes

Tags: php, mysql, forms, textarea, html-entities

I've been searching for ages and can't find this precise problem, but feel free to point me in the right direction if it has.

Simple Description: have a page that has a TEXTAREA on it. This TEXTAREA is to accept HTML as it's used to edit the home page of a client's website.

The aim is for this TEXTAREA to save to a VERY simple mySQL table.

PROBLEM: The problem is that if the TEXTAREA exceeds 512 characters is saves **nothing** to the database field. Under that it stores it fine.

Here's the code:

```
$homeTopLeft = addslashes(htmlentities($_GET['homeTopLeft'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8"));
$homeNews    = addslashes(htmlentities($_GET['homeNews'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8"));

mysql_login();

$query = "UPDATE cmsData SET homeTopLeft='$homeTopLeft', homeNews='$homeNews', lastUpdated=NOW() WHERE entry=1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(reportError('Unable to save new CMS data'));
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    echo '<p class="ok">Pages Successfully Updated!</p>';
    echo '<p style="border:1px dashed #ccc;">homeTopLeft = ' . $homeTopLeft . '</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p class="err">Unable to update the home page</p>';
}
```

I currently have the $_GET method as I'm actually calling the function via AJAX, which works fine under 512 characters.

**What It's Not**
- It's not the mySQL field size: Its data type is TEXT and I've manually increased the field through phpMyAdmin without error.
- It's not (as far as I can tell) the AJAX call, because it works if the TEXTAREA is < 512 Bytes
- The Collation (I don't think: I have it set to `latin1_general_ci` and have tried `latin1_bin` and some of the UFT ones)

**Final Note**
The actual database size of the field `homeTopLeft` has to be greater than 512 Bytes because of the `htmlentities` call.

I should also add that this occurs whether I'm just using a plain `TEXTAREA` or a `tinyMCE` rich text editor.

Any help you could offer would be gratefully received. Thanks!

Comment: just some suggestions: 1) you should not use addslashes for escaping (you can see this on the man page also http://php.net/addslashes) 2) even if the best alternative for the previous point would be mysql_real_escape_string in your case you should also check the man page to see that it is recommended to swtich to mysqli or pdo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a size limit on GET requests. For large things such as this, use POST

Comment: My current AJAX call is
 xmlhttp.open("POST","/php-bin/funcs_admin.php?pullIn=admin-page-editor&action=save&homeTopLeft="+topLeft+"&homeNews="+homeNews,true); - how do I update this to change it to 'POST'?

Comment: Thanks so much this was indeed the problem! All seems to be working now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you use GET method in your ajax you can't pass so much data to server as you wish, change it to POST and everything will work just fine.

Here you can find a short overview about that: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_real_escape_string over addslashes(htmlentities()). htmlentities normally should not go into the database. In addition to that, your database should use UTF8 for the table-charset, so sorting etc will be correct on foreign-language characters if you use them.

There is no known problem with text, that is larger than 512 bytes(!), if the corresponding field accepts it.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` gave me an error, I think due to magic quotes being enabled on my host's server (Goodness only knows why). This site will be run by English people for English-speakers in the UK so I'll hit the foreign language barrier when we get that far!

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string should not complain on magic quotes. a) anyways, change the hoster! :) b) Your problem could come from an too old mysql-server and/or php-version. Thats my guess...

Comment: Yep, I plan to speak with the hosts (we're a long-standing customer) and see if they will turn it off, as it's a pain in the behind.